# How to properly implement an async function with a script type module?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Inside my html file, I have a script tag, of type module, where I import functions from Firebase via CDN.

One such function is an await function called setDoc. I need to use setDoc within a function I have written called save() which is triggered by a button.

What I have tried:
The first error that I got is that save() "is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

I moved my save() function in a separate script tag (which is not a module type) and it now works and is triggered upon a button click. However, I can't use the await Firebase function even though my save() is prefixed with async, because I need to import the Firebase functions again within the separate script tag. But I can't import the Firebase functions without making the separate script tag's type "module". So it feels kind of a circular problem for me.

How can I go about implementing the await method setDoc properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply export the save method and import it and save it on window. As anything defined in a module is private to that module, explicity setting it on window is required.

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-69083332-using-an-exported-function-as-an-event-handler-s9x9x

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Exported Function as an event</title>
    <script type="module">
      import { save } from "./module.js";
      window.save = save;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="save()">
      Save
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**module.js**

```
export async function save() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert("Saved");
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, am I correct to assume that "alert("Saved")" is where I am supposed to place my await function (setDoc)?