# npm webpack-mix - calling javascript function from a file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, npm, webpack

I am trying to access function defined in `table.js` file from `index.html`.
**table.js**

```
    let table;

    function set_table(table) {
      this.table = table;
      console.log("function called successfully");
    }
    
    export {set_table};
```

**index.html**

```
    <script src="table.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      set_table("test");

    </script>
```

I'm using npm webpack mix to compile `table.js` and receiving the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: set_table is not defined`.

Please suggest the best way to access `table.js` function in `index.html`

Comment: Have you try to put <script src="table.js" type="text/javascript"></script> instead?

Comment: yes, I tried but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Module exports need to be set on `window`. So, just import `set_table` in script type="module" and then set it on `window` as `window.set_table`

```html
    <script type="module">
          import { set_table } from "./table.js";
          window.set_table = set_table;
        </script>
```

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69083651/1109657

Comment: Still getting an error
`Uncaught TypeError: window.set_table is not a function`

**index.html**
`
<script type="module">
          import { set_table } from "./table.js";
          window.set_table = set_table;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      set_table("test");
</script>
`

Comment: Don't know what you are doing but see this demo https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-69126176-using-an-exported-function-as-an-event-handler-forked-8olqc?file=/index.html

Comment: I found the solution, I need to import by defining it inside script.js of webpack-mix file to make it accessible on DOM level.